# Angular 2, sprintf in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, printf, angular

Can someone tell me all the steps I need to do to use a complete sprintf library (with zero padding and all other features typically present in a standard sprintf) in Angular 2 Typescript component? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Give me some code questions or point me to some resource questions are discouraged. Please add some code to your question that shows what you have tried and where you failed. https://www.google.at/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sprintf%20typescript points some links at the top that should get you started.

Comment: javascript dont have such standards

Answer (score 17):

Install sprintf-js

```
npm install sprintf-js --save
```

Install TypeScript Definition

```
typings install dt~sprintf-js --global --save
```

Import and use in code

```
import {sprintf} from "sprintf-js";

console.log(sprintf("%s %s!", "Hello", "Massimo"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As typings is deprecated now, maybe you update your answer with new approach for this? For example check headbozo's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45763578/1707258

Answer (score 12):

`npm i sprintf-js --save`

`npm i --save_dev @types/sprintf-js`

`import {sprintf} from "sprintf-js";`

Comment: It should be `npm i --save-dev @types/sprintf-js`, no?

Answer (score 7):

As typings is now deprecated:

`$ npm install --save @types/sprintf`

Then in your typescript source:

`import { sprintf } from 'sprintf';`

Comment: in ionic you need to write:  "import {sprintf} from "sprintf-js";"

Comment: I think the library name in @types should be the same. So It's 
`npm install --save @types/sprintf-js`

Answer (score 0):

Using ionic2.

None of the above solutions worked for me.

However, after running:

```
npm install sprintf-js --save

npm install --save @types/sprintf
```

I was able to use `require('sprintf-js')` in my `app.ts` file.

After that `vsprintf` and `sprintf` worked as long as I added

```
declare var vsprintf:any;
declare var sprintf:any;
```

at the top of the `ts` file that was using them.

Answer (score -2):

I answer my own question.

Download this library:
https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js

Add a reference to the sprintf.js file inside the head tag of the index.html main file:

```
<script src="assets/js/sprintf.js"></script>
```

Then, into the component, declare the main sprintf function as follow to use anyway in your code as usual.

```
declare var sprintf: any;

console.log(sprintf("%s %s!", "Hello", "Massimo")); // output : Hello Massimo!
```

Comment: where would you put `declare var sprintf: any;` ?

Comment: You have to declare it in the component that uses it, at the top under the import

Comment: This answer completely bypasses TypeScript by using `any` which supposedly was a requirement with the question.