# Angular2 or TypeScript: Left padding a String with Zeros

Tags: string, angular, typescript, padding

I have a number, let's say 9. But I need it as the string "09".

I know I can write my own logic. But I am looking for an implicit utility function which can pad the number.

I am using Angular2 with TypeScript. Looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469717/left-padding-a-string-with-zeros).

Just similar to Java:

```
String.format("%010d", Integer.parseInt(mystring));
```

Comment: See [How can I create a Zerofilled value using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript)

Comment: I dont think angularjs or angular2 provide such method

Comment: TypeScript and JavaScript have no built-in format or sprintf functions. You can use a [third-party one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36495685/6923555), if you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-pad-a-value-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can create your own function for this. To format the number you will have to convert it to a string first:

```
function pad(num, size) {
    let s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

TypeScript:

```
pad(num:number, size:number): string {
    let s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

**Edit:** There are a couple of better and more performant ways to do this.
See the discussion in this answer (I recommend reading most of the submitted answers if you got time): https://stackoverflow.com/a/9744576/1734678

**Update:** ECMAScript 2017 now has support for string padding:

```
str.padStart(targetLength [, padString])
str.padEnd(targetLength [, padString])
```

Check out [`padStart`'s documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

**EDIT:** As mentioned by others, since Angular 4 you can use this:

```
{{ myNumber | number:'2.0' }}
```

Comment: What happens if you have a negative number? Do you not end up with "00-2"

Comment: @SlimCheney I would think yes but just curious as to why you would need leading zeros in a negative number

Comment: People have such weird use cases don't they!! I needed to generate file name string so that files names end with a time offset eg ["z-090", "z-060", "z-030", "z+000", "z+030", "z+060"]

Answer (score 47):

Since Angular v4 there is DecimalPipe which let's easily add leading zeros: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

In your html, you can use then something like:

`{{ myNumber | number:'2.0' }}`

Comment: this introduces thousand separators not only padding

Comment: @Alejandro You can also use pipes in code. Just import it and call it or just call the corresponding transform method (I think Angular 6+). E.g. formatNumber(), see https://angular.io/api/common/formatNumber

Answer (score 35):

You can use one of below templates in HTML

```
{{ ("00" + 9).slice(-2) }} // 09
```

Or

```
{{ 9 | number: '2.' }} // 09
```

Or in component ts code file

```
var x = ("00" + 9).slice(-2);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for sharing. My code now:  {{r.HH | number: '2.'}}:{{r.MM | number: '2.'}} giving: eg. 03:00 in stead of 3:0

Answer (score 17):

if i want to pad **"0"** at the start and want the length of the String **str** to be **9**:

```
str.padStart(9 ,"0")
```

Answer (score 8):

With the latest Typescript, you can do:

```
let myStr:string = padLeft('123', '0', 6);  // '000123'

padLeft(text:string, padChar:string, size:number): string {
    return (String(padChar).repeat(size) + text).substr( (size * -1), size) ;
}
```

Comment: why not simply? `(String(padChar).repeat(size - text.length) + text)`

Comment: @JoelHarkes  Back in 2017, I do not believe the versions supported the repeat string function at that time.  ES5?

Answer (score 4):

```
public padIntegerLeftWithZeros(rawInteger: number, numberOfDigits: number): string {
    let paddedInteger: string = rawInteger + '';
    while (paddedInteger.length < numberOfDigits) {
        paddedInteger = '0' + paddedInteger;
    }
    return paddedInteger;
}

public zeroPadIntegerLeft3Digits(rawInteger: number): string {
    return this.padIntegerLeftWithZeros(rawInteger, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Pipe for that

```
{{ID |LeftPadFilter: ID}}



import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'LeftPadFilter',
    pure: false
})
export class LeftPadFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(item: string): string {
        return (String('0').repeat(2) + item).substr((2 * -1), 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export function Dx(num: any, dn: number = 2) {
  return ("0".repeat(dn) + Math.floor(num)).slice(-dn);
}
```