# Auto increment number in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My question is i want generete a auto increment number for my purchase order for every creation of a PO such as,

PO_000001 , PO_000002 ... etc

Please let me how to generate above way my auto increment number ,

Thank you

Comment: Ideal solution would be to do it in backend, as ID generations for a PO is something DB needs to handle.

Comment: I am using db as mongodb ,

Comment: use `str.padStart(targetLength [, padString])`, follow the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/40717803/9042256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the latest value in ur db. Ex: 1

When u are creating a new Purchase order just do it as **'PO_0000 + (db_value + 1)'**

Comment: Here I think we need to think about it. According to the question this `PO_` should be a string. rest of should be integer. So we will have to do more things. what happen if `db_value` is 100. then it will give you `PO_0000101` right ?. I think we should increase zeros in `PO_0000` Let me know if i wrong. Thanks

Comment: Yes sorry what u said is correct @DarshanaPathum. I didnt notice that

Comment: If you are updating the PO in db, please keep the entire thing in DB. You can use auto-increment feature available in most of the DB in a field and the same can be used for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is first of all make a auto increment field on your table. So when we need to add your `purchase_ID` you can get the maximum value of that auto increment fields. like

```
SELECT field_name FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

using above you can get the latest value of the table. then using that you can make your `purchase_ID` depend on that.

```
let latest_auto_increment_value = "" + db_value; // make integer to string
let def_val = "0000";
let purchase_ID = 'PO_' + def_val.substring(0, def_val.length - latest_auto_increment_value.length) + latest_auto_increment_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, This kind of operation is sensitive and secure for any domain, this should be stored in the backend like API or in table whenever you manage. from the frontend **Angular**, you have to manage a new purchase order every success order that will increment by its number should manage from backend like we know the primary key concept and auto-increment concept.
For Ref.

```
CREATE TABLE contacts
( contact_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(25),
  birthday DATE,
  CONSTRAINT contacts_pk PRIMARY KEY (contact_id)
);
```

Comment: Umang Naik, Manoj is expecting front-end for auto increment the number.