# Making one digit number as two digit using Angular Pipes

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I wanted to make `1` look as `01` on html and similarly `11` as `11`.

Can anyone please help me if there are such filters. Here is a sample [demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-number-format-pipe-gawcak?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Hi, just a hint, use the term **left padding** when doing your research

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836807/9183405

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 or TypeScript Left padding a String with Zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716894/angular2-or-typescript-left-padding-a-string-with-zeros)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular provides [Decimal Pipes](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) for these kind of situations. See a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50836807/9183405).

```html
<span>{{ number | number:'2.0' }}</span>
```

The Decimal Pipe's parameter accepts a string that represents your desired format. According to the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe#parameters), the format looks like this:

> number: '`{minIntegerDigits}`.`{minFractionDigits}`-`{maxFractionDigits}`'
>
> Where:
>
> - `minIntegerDigits`: The minimum number of integer digits before the decimal point. Default is 1.
> - `minFractionDigits`: The minimum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 0.
> - `maxFractionDigits`: The maximum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 3.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the the `padStart` method to add a specific character at the start of a string until it reaches a certain length.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'numberFormat'
})
export class NumberformatComponent implements PipeTransform {

  constructor() { }

   transform(n: string) {
     return n.padStart(2, '0');
   }
}
```